# only absolute definition (instead of relative) of path to Models in custom module is working for me. Why?

Tags: module, magento-1, extensions, configuration

I know that definition of path to Models and other stuff in Magento config.xml must be in absolute way. But in my case that didn't worked. Magento did not found my models. When I change definition in relative way Magento found my Models and module is now working fine.

Can anybody explain me why? Because I want develop Magento in correct way :).

Here is my example. path to Model:

> /app/code/local/Devpassion/Rowtotal/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Totalpopust.php

I try relative definiton which not worked for me:

```
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <rowtotal>
                        <class>rowtotal/quote_address_total_totalpopust</class>
                    </rowtotal>
                </totals>
            </quote>
```

And here is absolute way definition which works for me:

```
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <rowtotal>
                        <class>Devpassion_Rowtotal_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Totalpopust</class>
                    </rowtotal>
                </totals>
            </quote>
```

Answer (score 2):

The first method should work providing you have added rowtotal as the short-name for your models.

```
<global>
    <models>
        <rowtotal>
            <class>Devpassion_Rowtotal_Model</class>
        </rowtotal>
    </models>
</global>
```